# MS Access: Delete query to limit the number of records in a table to the most recent 10,000

Tags: sql, ms-access, jet

I am using MS Access 365.
I have a table containing records that is updated throughout the day.
Since this table can grow large, I want to limit the number of records in this table to the most recent 10,000 (recent is defined by a Timestamp field).
What combination of TOP LIMIT and SORT BY by can I use to create a query that deletes the oldest
N-10000 records

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I assume you have an `ID` field in your table which I named `tblData` then you could use the following SELECT statement to display all records which should be deleted

```
SELECT * FROM tblData
WHERE ID NOT IN 
(SELECT TOP 10000 tblData.ID
FROM tblData
ORDER BY tblData.dateStamp DESC);
```

In order to delete the data you only need to replace the first `SELECT`with a `DELETE`